# How do I ground two switches from the same box with one grounding wire?

Tags: wiring, grounding

I have a kitchen light with two light switches. One has been a dummy one (we thought) for 15 years until my husband went to replace the old faulty switch which operates the kitchen light. He replaced the old on/off switch with a 3-way switch and now our dining area light turns on (yay!!) but the kitchen lights won't. He is getting another on/off switch for the kitchen light and moving the 3 way to the previous dummy light-switch compartment.  Here is my question... There is only one grounding wire that we can see in the box.  How do we ground both light switches off of one grounding wire, or can we even do that?  Maybe that is why they didn't wire it correctly, to begin with?  Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: If a metal box then the switches uses the screws holding them to the box as ground.  Or can get some bare or green insulated wire and  add it to box and switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can daisy chain the same wire around both grounding terminals or you can splice your house me wire to 2 wires

Comment: It's perfectly OK to use one grounding wire and connect it to two switches. They are not designed to carry any current unless there is a fault. Put a pig-tail on the ground wire so you can ground both switches.  If it's a metal box, just attach the ground wire to the box and both switches will be grounded just by being installed in the box.